# Javascript functions not being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My website uses a nav bar which toggles divs on and off to go to different "pages".  Recently the buttons have stopped responding (nothing happens when clicked, and nothing appears in the console), and I have not been able to figure out why.

My nav bar is formatted like so:

```
<a href="#" id="videosButton">videos</a><br>
<a href="#" id="graphicButton">graphic design</a><br>
<a href="#" id="webButton">web design</a><br>
```

My pages are formatted like so:

```
<div id="videos" class="page">Videos page</div>
```

The JS is:

```
$('#videosButton').click(function () {
document.body.style.backgroundColor="rgb(192,57,43)"
$(".page").hide();
$('#videos').show();
});
```

for each button.  My JS file is being loaded, and I can view it in the console, so it's not an issue with that.  I have been struggling with this for hours and I am at a loss.  Can anybody help me understand why the nav bar is not behaving as expected?

**EDIT:** I have moved my external JS and jQuery to just before the closing `</body>` tag, and the problem persists.  I have put up the complete website at http://hdf.bl.ee/test/index.html if anyone thinks there is an issue not in the code I posted.

Comment: PS: Instead of `document.body.style.backgroundColor="rgb(192,57,43)"` you can use `$("body").css({backgroundColor: "rgb(192,57,43)"});` , it'll make you sleep better

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: In this case, there's zero reason to do that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: You have to ask my doctor... probably for the same reason `$('#videos').show();` can be used instead of `document.getElementById("videos").style.display="block";`

Comment: @Phil A typical case of Just Add jQuery™.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Please refrain from off-topic chatter in the comments.

Comment: @HenryFloyd on [your website](http://hdf.bl.ee/test/index.html) (currently) I cannot see you moved your script before the closing `</body>` - it's still right in the `head` of your page and it's not wrapped in DOM ready function.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I am not sure why you are unable to see the changes.  Please try refreshing your browser.

Comment: @HenryFloyd well, now it works - as you can see, since you also fixed your errors in JS with `favoriteMusic()` (instead of `favorite-music()`) functions etc.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan It turns out the issue was one miscellaneous <script> tag I had left in the head, the Google API script.  While I moved my personal JS file and jQuery both down to the bottom of the page, I did not delete that one from the head.  For some reason, when I deleted that one from the head, the other files started working fine.

Comment: @HenryFloyd I know... Well, happy coding and sleep more :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue was something else entirely.  Even though I moved my site's external JS file and the link to jQuery down to the `</body>` tag, they were being ignored because I had left one `<script>` in the `<head>` (the link to the Google API).  When I moved that down with the other scripts, everything sudden began working.  I am not sure why that was causing the other scripts to be ignored, but it solved my problem.

Comment: This answer does not directly answers your question. I can see your question is titled `"Javascript functions not being called"`,  you provided a [link-to-example](http://hdf.bl.ee/test/index.html) right into your question - And I can see you already have a **valid answer**.

Comment: None of the other answers solved my question.  It turns out my entire JS file was being ignored because of its placement in my page.

Comment: Interesting that by applying the changes I've mentioned the JS code on your website started working just fine. - Another suggestion - Currently you simply change pages using .show() .hide() - so the URL is not changing like i.e: `http://hdf.bl.ee/test/index.html#videos` which would allow you to send a link to a friend and he'd open directly the `#videos` page. Explore JS `hash` anchors; How to read a hash from URL; How to use JS's History API and pushState and popState.

Comment: Another suggestion - to make it more mobile friendly (loads of data to load even if your elements/pages are not visible), you could create separate pages like videos.html etc - and after a click - push that page's content using AJAX (without page refresh!).

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan  I had already moved the JS file and jQuery to the bottom of my page a full 55 minutes before you posted your suggestion to do so, and it did not fix the problem.   The problem was leaving a separate script in the head.  And I will research all of those things.  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 5):

Odds are that you're running that code **before** the element exists, and so `$("videosButton")` matches no elements, and so hooks up no handlers. Make sure the code is in a `script` tag **after** the markup for the elements in the HTML, or as a second-best approach, use jQuery's `ready` callback. Provided you do that, the function will get called:

```js
$('#videosButton').click(function () {
document.body.style.backgroundColor="rgb(192,57,43)"
$(".page").hide();
$('#videos').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="videosButton">videos</a><br>
<a href="#" id="graphicButton">graphic design</a><br>
<a href="#" id="webButton">web design</a><br>
My pages are formatted like so:

<div id="videos" class="page">Videos page</div>
```

Comment: I have moved all my scripts to the very end of the <body>, and the issue still persists, unfortunately.

Comment: @HenryFloyd: Then there's something going on that is not in your question.

Comment: I have put up my website at http://hdf.bl.ee/test/index.html if you think there is an issue that is not in the code I posted.

Comment: @HenryFloyd: That's not how it works: SO isn't just for helping you, now, it's for helping others in the future. External links rot: As soon as the problem is fixed, that link becomes useless. Instead, create an [MCVE](/help/mcve) and post it to your question.